# Error Starting MobileFirst Platform Operational Analytics for WebSphere Application Server Liberty

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am installing MobileFirst Platform Operational Analytics on WebSphere Application Server Liberty 8.5.5.1 as per [this guide](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/monitor/t_installing_op_analytics_liberty.html). As soon as I start the server it gives me the message on console:

```
INFO    ] SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: analytics.
[INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module analytics has been bound to default_host.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://hqdvwkl001:9080/analytics/
[INFO    ] SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/analytics
[INFO    ] SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.VirtualHost startWebApp" at ffdc_15.04.09_13.28.41.0.log
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: startWebApplication com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer startModule" at ffdc_15.04.09_13.28.41.1.log
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: startWebApplication com.ibm.ws.app.manager.web.internal.WebModuleHandlerImpl 142" at ffdc_15.04.09_13.28.41.2.log
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: startWebApplication com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.FutureMonitorImpl$FutureMonitorInfo 54" at ffdc_15.04.09_13.28.41.3.log
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0106E: Could not start web application analytics-ear.
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: startWebApplication com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction$1 applicationStartFail" at ffdc_15.04.09_13.28.42.0.log
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application analytics-ear. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: startWebApplication
```

Comment: Do you have the data from the FFDC logs that are mentioned?

Comment: Prerak, waiting to hear from you...

Comment: @IdanAdar I opened a PMR on this. FYI, following is the PMR no. : 36775,442,000.

Comment: Please supply an answer when the PMR is closed, or delete this question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I will post the answer as soon as I will get it. Till now I haven't heard from them since 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using MFP Operational Analytics 7.0 on Liberty Profile **8.5.5.1**.  The minimum version of Liberty Profile for MFP Operational Analytics 7.0 is **8.5.5.3**. Refer to system requirement document [here](http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=4DB072503A2F11E396F9FC10E99BE807&osPlatforms=AIX%7CLinux%7CMac%20OS%7CMobile%20OS%7CSolaris%7CWindows&duComponentIds=S004) and [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/r_supported_operating_systems_an.html)

After **upgrading** my test environment from Liberty Profile **8.5.5.1 to 8.5.5.3**, the issue was eliminated, and I was able to successfully start the Operational Analytics platform and access the analytics console.